# How to get firestore data from a loop and send to recyclerview adaptor

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am loading data from firestore into recycler view android. It is a kind of e-commerce cart system in which the items' Uids are stored.

I have my ArrayList of uids(*I've already received it from firestore*) and now with it, I need to get DocumentSnapshots of the items by looping the uids Arraylist and adding it to a ***documentSnapshots*** Arraylist.
I have tried the following:

```
ArrayList<DocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshots = new ArrayList<>();
                    
      //getting the document snapshot out of the uids
      for (int i = 0 ; i < uids.size() ; i++){
                        
                 db.collection("items").document(uids.get(i)).get()
                   .addOnCompleteListener(task1 -> {

                                    documentSnapshots.add(task1.getResult());
                                    
                                });
                    }
```

Then, after getting this data, I send this arraylist to the adaptor as follows:

```
//sending data to adaptor
adaptorCart = new AdaptorCart(Cart.this , modelCart , db , documentSnapshots);
```

But I always get the DocumentSnapshots Arraylist empty as because of the asynchronous behaviour of the onCompletelistener so how can I achieve what I want as always in this type of behaviour, I would get an empty list. Also, I tried using callback but couldn't get around the problem.

Any help would be so much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

```
     ArrayList<DocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshots = new ArrayList<>();
                
  //getting the document snapshot out of the uids
  int count = uids.size();
  for (int i = 0 ; i < uids.size() ; i++){
                    
             db.collection("items").document(uids.get(i)).get()
               .addOnCompleteListener(task1 -> {

                                documentSnapshots.add(task1.getResult());
                                if(documentSnapshots.size() == count){
                                  adaptorCart = new AdaptorCart(Cart.this , modelCart , db , documentSnapshots);
                                }
                                
                            });
                }
```

Comment: Okay, just a simple if statement! ThankYou very much!